# What is the recommended way to assign and change an event for button on a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which I want to be 'resusable' for a variety of situations. Mostly display and print information. The form has 2 buttons and a listbox

I want to be able to pass an object to the form that tells the form what the buttons are to do when pressed(for example show a MessageBox, Print out the contents of the listbox or close the form)

I am using an if statement to figure out what event to assign to my button...is there a better way to do this?

Ideally I would like to set the event from the initial calling code instead fo using an enum called 'Action'

```
     ==========calling code=================
                var information = new Information();                
                information.Action = Action.Print;
                var frmInformation = new frmInformation(information);
                frmInformation.Show(this);

    ====================information class======================
    public class Information
        {
            public delegate void OkButtonDelegate();        
            public IList<string> information{ get; set; }

            public Information()
            {
                information = new BindingList<string>();
            }

    ===============information form======================
     public partial class frmInformation : Form
        {
            private readonly Information _information;
            public Information.OkButtonDelegate _delegate;   

            public frmInformation(Information information)
            {
                _information = information;
                InitializeComponent();
                SetupForm();
            }


            private void SetupForm()
            {                         
                if (_information.Action== Action.Print)
                    _delegate = new Information.OkButtonDelegate(Print);
                else if (_information.Action == Action.Close)
                    _delegate = new Information.OkButtonDelegate(Close);
              }

        private void ShowMessageBox()
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("lalalalalala");
                }


                public static void Print()
                {
                    //take the contente out of listbox and send it to the printer
                }

 private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _delegate();

        }
```

Comment: Where do you use _delegate in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change it this way

```
switch (_information.Action) {
   case Action.Print:
      btnSend.Click += (s,e) => Print();
      break;
   case Action.Close:
      btnSend.Click += (s,e) => Close();
      break;
}
```

You won't need delegate type, generated Click handler and _delegate variable.